# JavaFX - Change drag and drop description

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

If you drag & drop a file in Windows explorer, the description changes depending on the target.

[image]

(from https://steveshank.com/cgi-bin/article.pl?aid=336)

How can I accomplish something similar in a JavaFX application (i.e. the target application is written in JavaFX).

Comment: Is that message part of Windows drag-and-drop or is it functionality added by File Explorer? If the latter, then you should be able the replicate the message using something like a `Tooltip` (or some other popup). If the former, pure JavaFX drag-and-drop doesn't offer similar functionality (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by placing the ‘feedback’ component in a Pane which overlaps your drag target, and making that Pane mouse-transparent.

When the target is a TreeView, a bit of extra work is needed, since TreeView doesn’t have a method for finding a TreeItem from pixel coordinates like Swing’s JTree has (as of JavaFX 12).

```
TreeView<Path> tree = new TreeView<>(root);

// Keep a list of all TreeCells, sorted by y-coordinate.
NavigableMap<Bounds, TreeCell<?>> cells = new TreeMap<>(
    Comparator.comparingDouble(Bounds::getMinY));

tree.setCellFactory(t -> {
    TreeCell<Path> cell = new TreeCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Path item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
                setGraphic(t.getTreeItem(getIndex()).getGraphic());
            }
        }
    };
    cell.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(
        (o, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
            cells.remove(oldBounds);
            cells.put(newBounds, cell);
        });
    return cell;
});

Pane feedbackPane = new Pane();
feedbackPane.setMouseTransparent(true);

Text arrow = new Text("\u279c ");
Text operation = new Text("?");
Text to = new Text(" to ");
Text target = new Text("?");
arrow.setStyle(
    "-fx-font-size: 150%;" +
    "-fx-font-weight: bolder;" +
    "-fx-fill: linear-gradient(darkblue, #2b9cff);" +
    "-fx-stroke: white;" +
    "-fx-stroke-width: 1px;" +
    "-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, gray, 4, 0, 2, 2);");
operation.setStyle("-fx-fill: mediumblue;");
to.setStyle("-fx-fill: mediumblue;");
target.setStyle("-fx-fill: navy;");

TextFlow feedbackLabel = new TextFlow(arrow, operation, to, target);
feedbackLabel.setMouseTransparent(true);
feedbackLabel.setVisible(false);
feedbackLabel.setStyle(
    "-fx-padding: 6px;" +
    "-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(white, lightgray);" +
    "-fx-border-color: black;" +
    "-fx-border-width: 1px;" +
    "-fx-border-radius: 0.75ex;" +
    "-fx-background-radius: 0.75ex;");
feedbackPane.getChildren().add(feedbackLabel);

tree.setOnDragOver(e -> {
    // Capitalize "Copy", "Move", or "Link".
    String opText = e.getTransferMode().toString();
    opText = opText.substring(0, 1) + opText.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    // Find row closest to drag location.
    Map.Entry<?, TreeCell<?>> entry =
        cells.floorEntry(new BoundingBox(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1));
    if (entry == null) {
        entry = cells.firstEntry();
    }
    // Use closest row's value.
    Object item = entry.getValue().getItem();

    feedbackLabel.setLayoutX(e.getX() + 10);
    feedbackLabel.setLayoutY(e.getY() + 10);
    operation.setText(opText);
    target.setText(String.valueOf(item));
    feedbackLabel.setVisible(true);
});
tree.setOnDragDone(e -> feedbackLabel.setVisible(false));
tree.setOnDragExited(e -> feedbackLabel.setVisible(false));

StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(tree, feedbackPane);
```